# How to add contact form 7 into my index.php

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I use wordpress. probably you heard contact form 7 which is plugin for wordpress. this plugin is used to add contact form on page. but if you add contact form on your wordpress page, you must add plugin's shortcut on admin panel. however i want to add this plugin on my index.php. how can i do that. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a form with required fields.
Create a Page for example create a page with name Home and then add the short_code of the form that you have created using contact-form-7, and then go to the wordpress settings menu in the wordpress admin and from that select reading and then from there you can find frontpage display settings from there you can choose the option which ever you need. For our solution you need to select the page with the form as to be displayed as front page.
[See it Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Reading_Screen)

Hope this helps you